# How to secure a Windows ME system connected to the internet?

Tags: windows, networking, security, firewall, anti-virus

I am about to re-install Windows ME on an old Dell Dimension 4300. The computer is connected to the internet via a 2Wire 3600HGV DSL modem/router.

What do I need to secure the computer?

- Do I need a software firewall? Or is the router sufficient?
- Is antivirus software necessary if I don't download anything?

It will be part of a local LAN, so I don't want to jeopardize any of the other PCs on the home network.

NOTE: I'm looking to run some older (non-DOS) computer games that don't run well (or at all) on XP and newer systems.

NOTE 2: When I say 'secure', I'm not looking to actively browse the web on the machine. I was curious as to what risks I be facing if I simply had this PC connected to my local network (and thus the internet).

Comment: If you aren't planning on browsing the Internet, why connect it to the network at all? That way, you aren't putting your LAN at risk.

Comment: I'd like it to be on the LAN, hence a wired ethernet connection. Can I prevent internet access while still permitting local network traffic?

Comment: @Frank yes, this can be done from your router/gateway in most cases.

Comment: Gack! Why would someone voluntarily choose to install WinMe?! :) For old games I used a non-networked copy of Win98SE for many years, besides real DOS of course.

Comment: You are almost guaranteed more speed (and better security - you can take/restore snapshots of the current state) by simply running inside a virtual machine on any modern host system. Take a look at VirtualBox. (However, do note that VBox doesn't have very smooth mouse support on 98 guests. VMware does work well, speaking from experience.)

Comment: +1, Installing ME in a VM is the best solution. Then @Frank also doesn't need to care about creating new router/firewall rules.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; I'll check out VirtualBox and also see how flexible my router setup is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

1. Disconnect it from the internet, or
2. Isolate it from the internet via hardware firewall

Windows ME is unsupported and has been for the better part of a decade. I regularly see malware that will infect it.

At the risk of sounding like a zealot, what do you need that machine for? You may want to consider running Kubuntu or another friendly Linux distribution on it.

Comment: Looking to simply run some older computer games and miscellaneous applications that don't play well with XP or newer... This may be a silly question, but is it possible to isolate it from the Internet while allowing TCP/IP traffic on the local network?

Comment: And pardon my ignorance, but would this malware be a threat if I didn't browse the internet at all with this machine? Am I at risk simply by plugging in the ethernet cord so to speak?

Comment: Yes, you could isolate the machine from the Internet but allow access to the LAN. Your router might be able to do that, but don't bank on your other LAN machines not infecting it, or one of the games. In fact, I would bet on that happening. Yes, malware is still a threat from other machines on the LAN. You might want to look into Dosbox or wine to run the games.

Answer (score 5):

Windows ME left extended support on [July 11th, 2006](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/default.aspx?LN=en-ca&x=16&y=11&p1=6519). It is no longer possible to secure that operating system.

For comparison, Windows XP is leaving extended support on [April 8, 2014](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows/products/lifecycle). At that time, it will no longer be supported either, and you should assume it cannot be securely connected to a network.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Perhaps a better question to ask would be: If I'm not browsing the internet on the machine, what kind of risks do I face by simply having it connected to the internet (via my home LAN, behind the router)?

Answer (score 0):

I've just looked up some of the specifications of the Dell Dimension.
It would be easier and safer just to install a lightweight distribution of Linux. (Crunchbang, Puppy, Lubuntu to name a few).
If you want Windows, try installing Windows XP as Windows ME does not have any regular security updates and most of the newer browsers require XP and up.

Sorry for the off-topic. You should be fine with the inbuilt firewall of the router.

As for the Anti-Virus, it's a good practice to have one on a Windows computer, but the key-word is common sense. Don't visit suspicious websites, don't go beyond your personal 'safe-zone' and you shouldn't get any viruses. If you do, by any chance get a virus, download and run a on-demand scanner, fix the problem and uninstall it.

Comment: Thanks for checking the specs. I would consider a Linux distribution, but in my case, I am looking to re-install Windows ME simply to have a legacy system for some older games and applications that don't run well or at all on XP or newer. I don't anticipate using the machine for any internet browsing, so my main concern was whether or not simply being connected to the internet was putting me at risk for any sort of malware.

Comment: If they are DOS games, use DOSBox (http://www.dosbox.com/) on a modern PC

Comment: I have DOSBox and it's an excellent tool, so thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, in this case, the programs are not DOS, but Windows 95/98 vintage. I also have some hardware, like a scanner that only has drivers for Windows 9x systems.

Answer (score 0):

Even when it was supported, windows me was a bit of a pig, and most enthusiasts in the know preferred windows 98se. I had a pretty good experience with it, mainly cause I was lucky enough to accidentally 'upgrade' windows 98 with it, and it still worked.

Most Antivirus does not work with windows 98 - heck I remember having trouble finding an AV that would work on the very excellent windows 2000(which might be a better option here!). clamwin is about the only regularly updated option. Firewalls... I haven't even bothered looking - if you can seperate the windows 98 box into its own vlan, that might be great. Being able to connect to the local network may be of limited use, depending on whether windows me supports smb/cifs (its been so long I've forgotten)

To me, the smart money is on isolating the system from the network totally, and should you need to download anything to the system, sneakernet it, or boot into a more modern OS (linux as suggested) for anything that needs the net.

In the modern context, windows me is a curiosity, that really belongs in the side show tent. Treat it that way.